# How to get basic data with the new Google Ads API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-ads-api

About a year ago, Google AdWords changed their name to Google Ads and now they complicated Google Ads API. Their [official library](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start) doesn't work and I don't know where I should get information from.

My questions:

1. How I can get all Google Ads scopes like [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/authorization#OAuth2Authorizing)
2. How `LIST` function for Google Ads looks like in JavaScript? (to get basics Google Ads user data) [Link](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/list?apix=true#try-it)

**Note:**

Doesn't work anymore:

- `gapi.client.load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/adwords/v2/rest')`
- `gapi.client.load('googleads', 'v3')`
- `gapi.client.load('adwords', 'v2')`
- `gapi.client.load('https://googleads.googleapis.com/v2/customers')`

One working scope for Google Ads:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords`